# Get Documents ID list of a Firestore sub collection in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried everything but I'm still missing something because I always get empty list.
The goal is to extract the IDs of the users with whom I have exchanged messages, knowing only the ID of the logged in user.

I have the following data structure on Firestore:

- **Collection** users

  - **Documents** id = logged user uid

    - **field** name, mobile phone, mail...
    - **Collection** chat

      - **Documents 1** id = other user uid Frank

        - **Collection** Messages

          - **Document** id of specific chat message

            - **field** text value of the chat message
      - **Documents 2** id = other user uid John

        - **Collection** Messages

          - **Document** id of specific chat message

            - **field** text value of the chat message

I tried to write code in n different ways like:

```
     final chatDocs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance 
    .collection('users') 
    .doc('eMHSyaD76dX8qcxxJjy7lIK4AiD3') 
    .collection('chat') 
    .get(); 
    final userIds = chatDocs.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
```

but the result is always the same... the list of document ids inside the chat sub collection is always empty.

I thought it might be a problem with the rules on Firestore, but I have the most permissive default ones:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 12, 31);
    }
    }
```

Has anyone had the same problem?
The last solution is to create a separate top-level document where I can save the IDs of the users with whom I have exchanged messages.

Thanks in advance
Enrico

I expect to get a list of 2 items

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might help if you show the exact data you're working with, perhaps with a screenshot of the database along with the exact code used for the query. We should be able to see that your query definitely matches your data (it sounds like they just don't match).

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you very much. Hi just edited my post.

Comment: The documents in the chat subcollection don't exist and can't be queried.  You can tell because they're in italics.  The only reason why they are listed there is because they contained further nested subcollections, and you can use what you see in the console to navigate into them.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I didn't know that a document containing only a collection remains empty if the classic fields are not present.
I read everywhere and honestly I would never have come to this conclusion.

A curiosity: but is it also written in the official documentation?
Thanks again

Enrico

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents